# creating a table from 1 to 100 in php nested in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is a practice question I am having a problem with. So far, what I got to create is a table using the following code. I need help to fix it, with explanation on what my mistakes are.

What I am trying to to do is pretty simple: generating numbers from 1 to 100 in a table using php nested in an html code

Each 10 numbers should be in an aligned row, then break after 10

```
| 1 | 2 | . . . | 10 |

|11 | 12| ....  | 20 |

|21 | 22| ....  | 30 |
.
.
.
|91| 92 | ...   |100|

<table border="1">
<?php
    for ($x=1; $x <= 100; $x++){
        if($x%11 ==0) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . "<br>" . "</tr></td>";
        }
        echo "<tc><td>" . $x . "</td></tc>" ;
    }
?>
</table>
```

Also using a `for` statement for the loop with `if` statement nested in it for the break the row

Could someone point out my mistakes in this code please.

all right the correct code should be like this:

```
<table border="1">
<?php
    for ($x=1; $x <= 100; $x++){
        if($x%10 ==1) {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>" . $x . "</td>" ;
    }
?>
</table>
```

Thank you all for the help

Comment: I'll give you a couple of clues: `for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)` and `%`... but I'm not going to do your homework for you

Comment: @Ahmed : Welcome to stackoverlow.  You should post what you have tried when asking for help.

Comment: % is your answer ... look up modulus. It basically returns the remainder of dividing one number by another. Extremely useful for many different scenarios.

Comment: You are closing your html tags in the wrong order. The most recently opened tag must be closed first to form a tree-structure.

Comment: You also want `$x % 10` surely, not `$x % 11`

Comment: BE carefull though, modulus is slow! You might not want to use it in heavy loops. This isnt a big deal, but dont use it as a magic solution :)

Comment: You could use `array_chunk`, or do you must use an `if`-statement?

Answer (score 4):

We need to first understand the requirement.

Requirement:

1. Need incremental counter horizontally.
2. Every row should contain a whole 10 numbers starting from say 1 to 10, 11 to 20 etc.
3. So, if we consider the output as HTML table, `<tr>` increments by `11` and `<td>` increments by `1`.
4. So, we need two loops: once incrementing by `10`: the outer loop and other incrementing by `1`: the inner loop.
5. So, write outer loop and inside it, add inner loop, both have step: `1`
6. So, outer loop will increment the counter and inside it, inner loop will also run.
7. For every outer loop, the inner loop will run 10 times.
8. Thus, we get exact rows: `1-10`, `11-20`

Try this:

```
<table>
       <?php
       $k=0;
       for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
       ?>
       <tr>
           <?php
           for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
           ++$k;
           ?>
           <td><?php print $k;?></td>
           <?php
           }
           ?>
       </tr>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
</table>
```

Comment: to save a variable: `k = i*10 + j` Also you should really use `echo` instead. All those `<?php ?>` tags makes it look bad.

Comment: @Ahmed, is my answer solution to your question?

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to write the code, i just edited the , Filip Haglund, well as you see my code only got one <?php and the closing ?> and this is what i learned so far, first class of PHP, i hope i am learning the right methods

Comment: @Ahmed, please reply to my comment.

Comment: thank you for the suggested code, it is not what i am trying to do, as i mentioned i need to nest an if statement in a for loop, plus i know it is about the % which i am trying to fix up now, seriously with a calc. in my hand and i am trying to figure out what is wrong, i concluded that the if statement should be  if ($x%2 ==0.5) then the same code in my mian post, but that didnt work either, actually i got the all the numbers in separate cell table one only one row !?

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent well your code is not an if statement nested in a for loop, yes it did output an organized table from 1 to 100, but not in a cells ? i just edited my code, and as i mentioned in my previous comment am not sure what is wrong with my if statement, mathematically it could be if($x%2 ==0.5) but it also didnt give me a right organized output ? it was one row table with each number in a cell, it should break to another row after 10, 20 and 30 ... so on like the table in the code you provided

Comment: so i guess its on me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
           $p = $col * $row;
           echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<table>
    <?php
    for ($x=1; $x <= 100; $x++)
    {
        if($x%10 ==1)
        **{
            echo "<tr><td>" . "<br>" . "</tr></td>";**
        }
        echo "<tc><td>" . $x . "</td></tc>" ;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```